# Missing thumbnails in Assets

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, file-manager, thumbnails

Images were working in EE's native File Manager, but were blank in Assets. I checked all the usual suspects, reindexed them with native EE File Manager and Assets, but the problem persisted. Andris at [Pixel & Tonic](http://pixelandtonic.com) pointed to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out my database.php file had an extra blank line at the beginning.
(see that extra line?) And this was corrupting output in EE.

[image]

Any php file that is included (called by the main php file) needs to have the opening php tag on the first line! Otherwise bad things will happen.